# Concatenate 2 Julia Arrays without modifying them

Tags: arrays, list, julia

I would like to concatenate 2 arrays.

```
julia> l1=["a","b"]
2-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 "a"
 "b"

julia> l2=["c","d"]
2-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 "c"
 "d"
```

`append!` can do this but this function is modifying `l1` (that's a function named with a `!`)

```
julia> append!(l1, l2)
4-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 "a"
 "b"
 "c"
 "d"

julia> l1
4-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 "a"
 "b"
 "c"
 "d"
```

I was looking for a `append` function (without exclamation point).

But such a function doesn't seems to exist.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In addition to @oleeinar's answer, you can use `hcat` and `vcat` to concatenate arrays:

```
l3 = vcat(l1, l2)
4-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 "a"
 "b"
 "c"
 "d"
```

You can also concatenate horizontally with `hcat`:

```
l4 = hcat(l1, l2)
2x2 Array{ASCIIString,2}:
 "a"  "c"
 "b"  "d"
```

Answer (score 9):

you can 'join' the arrays by

```
l3 = [l1; l2]
```

Comment: This syntax actually calls vcat "under the hood".

Comment: Both run at the same speed.  But, cat(   , dims=1), which is semantically vcat, runs much slower.