# Concatenating arrays in Julia

Tags: julia

If the two `Int` arrays are, `a = [1;2;3]` and `b = [4;5;6]`, how do we concatenate the two arrays in both the dimensions? The expected outputs are,

```
julia> out1
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6

julia> out2
3x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  4
 2  5
 3  6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate 2 Julia Arrays without modifying them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206550/concatenate-2-julia-arrays-without-modifying-them)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use the `vcat` and `hcat` functions:

```rb
julia> a, b = [1;2;3], [4;5;6]
([1,2,3],[4,5,6])

help?> vcat
Base.vcat(A...)

   Concatenate along dimension 1

julia> vcat(a, b)
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6

help?> hcat
Base.hcat(A...)

   Concatenate along dimension 2

julia> hcat(a, b)
3x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  4
 2  5
 3  6
```

Answer (score 34):

Square brackets can be used for concatenation:

```
julia> a, b = [1;2;3], [4;5;6]
([1,2,3],[4,5,6])

julia> [a; b]
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6

julia> [a b]
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  4
 2  5
 3  6
```

Comment: This is syntactic sugar for `vcat` and `hcat` respectively: `[e.head for e in [:([a; b]), :([a b])]] # Symbol[:vcat,:hcat]`

Comment: Generally I think `vcat` and `hcat` should be preferred because this solution is whitespace sensitive. For example: `[a - b] ` will `vcat` while `[a -b]` will `hcat`. That can be a nasty bug to find.

Comment: It seems a bit backward to *not* prefer the syntactic sugar version. After all, what's the sugar *for*? Are you saying that this syntax will probably be removed?

Answer (score 17):

You can use the `cat` function to concatenate any number of arrays along any dimension. The first input is the dimension over which to perform the concatenation; the remaining inputs are all of the arrays you wish to concatenate together

```
a = [1;2;3]
b = [4;5;6]

## Concatenate 2 arrays along the first dimension
cat(1,a,b)
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6

## Concatenate 2 arrays along the second dimension
cat(2,a,b)
3x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  4
 2  5
 3  6

## Concatenate 2 arrays along the third dimension
cat(3,a,b)
3x1x2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1
 2
 3

[:, :, 2] =
 4
 5
 6
```

Comment: More recent versions would require the `dims` keyword, e.g. `cat(a,b,dims=3)`

Answer (score 2):

when encountered Array{Array,1}, the grammer is a little bit different, like this:

```
julia> a=[[1,2],[3,4]]
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2]
 [3, 4]

julia> vcat(a)
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2]
 [3, 4]

julia> hcat(a)
2×1 Array{Array{Int64,1},2}:
 [1, 2]
 [3, 4]

julia> vcat(a...)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4

julia> hcat(a...)
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  3
 2  4
```

ref:

> ... combines many arguments into one argument in function definitions
>   In the context of function definitions, the ... operator is used to combine many different arguments into a single argument. This use of ... for combining many different arguments into a single argument is called slurping

Answer (score 2):

Functional way to concatanate 2 arrays is to use `reduce` function.

```
a = rand(10, 1)
b = rand(10, 1)
c = reduce(hcat, [a, b])
```

Comment: For two arrays it's not that important, but when you want to concatenate multiple arrays, this method is an _enormous_ performance gain over `hcat(arrays...)`.